# CodeIgniter + Session usage with Redis is slow

Tags: php, codeigniter, redis, codeigniter-3

I'm migrating my application with CodeIgniter 3 to use Redis as a session manager, but as it makes many requests in AJAX I noticed that they tend to take longer, 11 requests that in all took 300ms now take 11s.

I made some code changes to get all sessions at the beginning of each controller, put the values in a model and after that I run `session_write_close()`.

The request time even improved, lowering the time to an average of 3 - 5s, but far from ideal.

Reading the CodeIgniter documentation I saw this:

> CodeIgniter’s Session library does NOT use the actual ‘redis’
> session.save_handler.

With that I decided to disable the autoload of the native CodeIgniter session and directly use the `session_start()` at the beginning of the Controllers before getting the session values and feeding my Model.

To my surprise, the application read the data again in less than 300ms.
And even not using `session_write_close()` anymore, it still continued at the same speed.

What could be happening with CodeIgniter that makes it take longer to connect and read the session in Redis?

Comment: Same here. How did you solve that?

Comment: @daryn-k From what I checked on the CodeIgniter forum/github, it executes a 1-second `sleep` when it detects more than one access in the same session, hence the delay..
I stopped using the CodeIgniter session and started using PHP's native `session_start()` from PHP.
But you should be careful with tasks that can be called in parallel and write the same session. In my case it was uploading files in parallel.
More details: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/6233